# Accessing $_POST array data with jQUery .val()?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jQuery plugin ([tag-it](http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/js/tag-it.js)), which generates the form input field:

```
function create_choice (value){
            var el = "";
            el  = "<li class=\"tagit-choice\">\n";
            el += value + "\n";
            el += "<a class=\"closetag\">x</a>\n";
            el += "<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"display:none;\" value=\""+value+"\" name=\"item[tags][]\">\n";
            el += "</li>\n";
            var li_search_tags = this.tag_input.parent();
            $(el).insertBefore (li_search_tags);
            this.tag_input.val("");
        }
```

The input field generated by above function can be accessed in HTML form in following way:

```
<ul id="mytags"></ul>
```

I can access the tags array by submitting form with PHP like:

```
$tags = $_POST['item']['tags'];
```

Can I get the above array without $_POST using jQuery .val() or some other method? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if you can use jQuery in the PHP code on the server-side?

Comment: @Norman H: I just want to post this array data with uploadify plugin, which basically takes the form input data with `.val()`

Comment: So your question is really nothing to do with PHP's `$_POST` ... you just want to retrieve the value or state of various hidden `<input />` fields. Yes?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Sorry if my question is not clear. I want to POST the form data with the uploadify script, which gets form fields values like `$('#name').val()` . But I'm using this tags plugin which has hidden input, therefore I'm having difficulty to retreive the hidden value and post to uploadify. I'll greatly thankful if you can help with it.

Comment: `hidden` fields are still part of the form. If the plugin doesn't include their values in the `POST` request, then it has a bug. You should contact the authors. (BTW, I don't know why you force `display: none` through CSS; `type="hidden"` inputs are already invisible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elems = $('input[name="item[tags][]"]');
var array = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
   array.push($(elems[i]).val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the tags on the client you can do:

```
var tags = [];
$('li.tagit-choice > input[type=hidden]').each( function() {
    tags.push( $(this).val() );
});
```

Or, if -- as you comment -- you just need the values from the form serialized.

```
$('form').serialize();
```

works, too.

Answer (score 0):

serializeArray() seems to be designed for what you want to do.

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

EDIT: Ok, you can use serializeArray(), but a bit more code is needed:

```
$.map($('#test').serializeArray(), function (n) {
  if (n.name == 'item[tags][]') {
    return n.value;
  }
});
```

Comment: serializeArray won't get the value of the elements.  It will just put the objects into an array.